# Node.js v16.20.2 crashes beyond 16GB despite specifying --max-old-space-size=16384. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am in a linux vm were output of free -h is
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G        126G         99G         69M         25G        123G
Swap:          111G         10G        101G

This machine is a shared machine, which means multiple user in my organization can access its memory and run its on process.

I am trying to run my application on this machine using node command as
node --max-old-space-size=16384 --expose_gc myapplication.js

Output of my top command at a random instant after starting my application is like this:
`
top - 22:07:27 up 112 days, 11:43, 44 users,  load average: 6.06, 6.36, 5.25
Tasks: 906 total,   7 running, 874 sleeping,  18 stopped,   7 zombie
%Cpu(s): 23.2 us,  5.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 71.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 26329340+total,   893864 free, 25478662+used,  7612924 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 11724390+total, 10161080+free, 15633100 used.  7595188 avail Mem

PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+  COMMAND
183034 swapnil   20   0   11.3g  16.2g   9364 R 365.1  4.2  59:19.53   node
152575 person2   20   0   32.7g   1880   1140 R 199.3  0.0  42638:03   code
137793 person3   20   0  199.5g 184.4g   1984 R  99.7 73.5  53:09.58   custom_cmd`

Surprisingly, even though i specified  --max-old-space-size=16384 (~ 16GB) my node application crashes and shows OOM beyond 16GB like this
<--- Last few GCs --->
 `[3492:0x45d8910] 2304647 ms: Scavenge 16224.8 (16989.1) -> 16222.2 (16994.8) MB, 276.3 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.582, current mu = 0.602) task [3492:0x45d8910] 2305511 ms: Scavenge 16229.5 (16995.1) -> 16227.2 (17000.6) MB, 270.5 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.582, current mu = 0.602) task [3492:0x45d8910] 2306587 ms: Scavenge 16235.9 (17000.6) -> 16233.7 (17000.8) MB, 354.7 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.582, current mu = 0.602) task`

From the output of top command you can see my PID swapnil is using only very less % of MEM but still somehow node gives OOM beyond 16gb, I am struggling for 2 weeks but just cannot figure out why is it crashing even after specifying the max-old-space-size=16384?

Is it related to node version (v16.20.2) that I am using where it is expandable only to 16 gb is it something like that?

For the community info I ran a test.js file to check my max heap size limit
temp.js
`const maxHeapSz = require('v8').getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit;
const maxHeapSz_GB = (maxHeapSz / 1024 ** 3).toFixed(1);

console.log('--------------------------');
console.log(`${maxHeapSz_GB}GB`);`

Command run:
`node --max_old_space_size=655360000  src/cmd/temp.js ; node --max-old-space-size=4096 src/cmd/temp.js ; node --max-old-space-size=2048 src/cmd/temp.js ; node --max-old-space-size=1024 src/cmd/temp.js ; node --max-old-space-size=512 src/cmd/temp.js`
Here deliberately i set the flag to 655360000 value to see how far heap can expand and result is even more surprising

### Output:
Output is

### 640000.0GB

### 4.0GB

### 2.0GB

### 1.0GB

0.5GB

Please help like why node is crashing beyond 16gb even though system has resources?

I tried setting the max-old-space-size flag to 16384 but still my application crashes and throws OOM beyond 16 gb, please see my top command output as well and my free -h output.